# How can I use \b boundary around special characters

Tags: python, regex

`\b✅\b` do **not** match a single emoji: '✅'.

`\b\u2B07\b` do **not** match: '⬇️'.

\b-\b do **not** match '-'.

`\bfoo\b` certainly match 'foo'.

Why does that happens and what's an alternative to ensure my emoji or any special character is not in the middle of a string

playground: https://regex101.com/r/jRaQuJ/2

Comment: `\b` is supposed to work between a word and a non-word character only

Comment: Hm, thanks. Is there a way to avoid another characters around a sigle special character?

Comment: `(?<!\w)✅(?!\w)` or are you looking for spaces? What does "not in the middle of a string" mean, exactly? All characters could be interpreted as "being in the middle of a string" presumably.

Comment: 'Cause neither ✅, nor ⬇️, nor `-` are `\w`.

Comment: @ggorlen I think this is what I'm looking for, thanks

Comment: @LeonardoRick - Closing doesnt mean deleting.  Its to stop people from replying to it.  All questions will remain and this points to the other two.

Comment: Neither of the dupes deal with emoji. This is another [victim of regex tag policing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate), 2 delete votes up on a perfectly normal question.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah, for beginners might be confusing to understand how to classify an emoji in the regex world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?<!\w)✅(?!\w)
```

This uses negative lookarounds to match an emoji with no word characters on either side.

The reason for the matches you asked about is that `\b` is a zero-width boundary where one side of the boundary is `\w` (a word character, or `[0-9A-Za-z_]`) and the other is the beginning or end of the string or `\W` (a non-word character).

For example, consider the string `"foo."`:

```
start of string boundary (zero width)
     |
     |   non-word character
     |   |
     v   v
      foo.
      ^ ^
      | |
word characters
```

The `\b` boundary could be used in the regex `\bfoo\b` and find a match thanks to the boundary between `o` and `.` characters and the boundary between the beginning of the string and the character `f`.

`"foobar"` does not match `\bfoo\b` because the second `o` and `b` don't satisfy the boundary condition, that is, `b` isn't a non-word character or end of the string.

The pattern `\b-\b` does not match the string `"-"` because `"-"` isn't a word character. Likewise, emojis are built from non-word characters so they won't respond to the boundary as a word character does as is the case with `\bfoo\b`.

Comment: Can someone explain why this received -2 votes? I'd love to improve it but I don't know what the issue is.